# How to run hello world FUSE program on Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, filesystems, fuse

I would like to know the configurations to run this [Hello World](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html) program on Xcode. I have installed MacOSXFUSE.
With the command

```
gcc -Wall hello.c `pkg-config osxfuse --cflags --libs` -o hello
```

and then with

```
./hello outputdrive -f -s
```

I am able to successfully mount the drive outputdrive.

I have environmental variable `declare set as -x PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"`

MacOSXFUSE is installed in `/usr/local/include/osxfuse/`

More information:

`/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/osxfuse.pc`

data in this file is

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: fuse
Description: OSXFUSE
Version: 2.7.3
Libs: -L${libdir} -losxfuse -pthread  -liconv
Cflags: -I${includedir}/osxfuse/fuse -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE
```

A little progress,

I did this on terminal,

```
pkg-config osxfuse --cflags --libs
```

Pasted the below result in "other c flags" in xocde

```
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE -I/usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse -L/usr/local/lib -losxfuse -pthread -liconv
```

Now I get the below error,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_fuse_main_real", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please let me know if more details is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the /usr/local/lib in the "Library search paths" and the library "libosxfuze" to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

does it compile from command line?
g++ hello.c -I/usr/local/include/osxfuse/fuse -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -v -L/usr/local/lib -losxfuse